# VS code npm extention for autocomplete not work for me

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm new with npm and javascript and trying to write some simple code on VS code.
I have installed the `JavaScript (ES6) code snippets` and `npm Intellisense`, but it don't work for me.
for example, I'm trying to use `validator` with a different validator's function, but don't get any suggestions for completion.

Any idea?

Comment: This seems to be an issue specifically with `validator` which also doesn't work for me. It works with other packages like `mongoose`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i use `import validator from "validator";`.
`const validator = require('validator')` doesn't trigger intellisense.